# How to process dot to dot puzzle images to convert them into lists of points?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to process this image to convert it to a list of points, is this possible? Output data will preserve the order, so I need to process the positions of the dots and also the index numbers of those dots.

Example output:

**(0.233, 0.17)**

**(0.234, 0.173)**
...

[Example Image](http://www.1max2coloriages.fr/coloriages/relier-points/canards.jpg)

I'm looking for something that can be written in any programming language, or I can use softwares if there is something out there for this task. I will use this solution in a set of images for once, output will be in my project.

Comment: do you need list of coordinates of points from 1 to 394 in increasing order like coordinate of point 1 then point 2 and so on ?

Comment: @krishna yes, I need them to have same order.